# Calling Rest resource issue from Force.com sites

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, restresource

I have rest resource class which i am calling from force.com site..

Below is my endpoint

https://cs22.force.com/services/apexrest/CustomerData/

```
  @RestResource(urlMapping='/CustomerData/*')
global without sharing class CustomerInfoDataRest {

  @HttpGet
  global static List<Account> getAccountInfo() {
    //String companyName = RestContext.request.params.get('companyName');
    List<Account> companyList = [ Select ID, Name, personemail, BillingState from Account];


    return companyList;

  }
}
```

**Error i am getting**

```
<Errors><Error><errorCode>FORBIDDEN</errorCode><message>You do not have access to the Apex class named: CustomerInfoDataRest</message></Error></Errors>
```

I have checked Force.com site profile..I already have permission to the class CustomerInfoDataRest in that profile.

I have API enabled as well on Site profile..I have no idea why i am getting this error..

[image]

Comment: Is this webservice public? i couldnt hit it.. its asking me for session id

Comment: Is you site hosted on same org ? Are all classes native to you ? Did you tried calling through curl/hurl to test your api ?   Read [this](http://www.oyecode.com/2014/08/start-building-your-own-rest-api-in.html) and [this](http://www.oyecode.com/2014/07/try-any-salesforce-api-quickly-with.html) two my blog post to see if you are doing correctly. If problem persist share and lets us know

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions:

1. Is there any namespace for you org, if yes use this format for endpoint url: https://cs22.force.com/services/apexrest/*mynamespace*/CustomerData
2. Ensure class visibility is enabled for public access settings. i guess you are already doing that.
3. ensure the site profile has access to account object and account fields referred in the service.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your endpoint.

You need use the site url

**Example:**

SITE URL : mySite.force.com

SERVICE URL SITE : https://mySite.force.com/services/apexrest/CustomerData/

Regards